# Google Game Services cloud save STATUS_DEVELOPER_ERROR

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-play-games

I use Google Game Services not in the first time, I have 2 apps using it and doing it ok. 
Now I'm working on another app and found that even though it's connected to Google Play Game Services and shows me a user's name it can't use cloud save state feature. 
My android app was published and then unpublished, so it is not a draft. Game (in Game Services Tab of Google Play Developer Console) also is published. I have two linked apps with the same package name and different SHA1 footprints: for debug eclipse and release version (as suggested by Google).

I've tried my old app on this emulator (genymotion) and it works and saves state.

I've double checked everything according to 
https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting, but it looks that averything is ok.

But when trying to save app state both in release or debug apk I get the same STATUS_DEVELOPER_ERROR and in logcat I see the same message:

> [97] a.a: Unexpected response code 403 for
>   https://www.googleapis.com/appstate/v1/states/3 Error executing
>   operation: Access Not Configured. The API is not enabled for your
>   project, or there is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on
>   your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please
>   use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.

Of course I've checked Google Developers Console and see that Google+ API, Google Play Game Services, Google Play Game Management and Drive API are on. I've even created a new Game  (in Game Services Tab of Google Play Developer Console) and relinked my app to it, the same result: connection ok, yet STATUS_DEVELOPER_ERROR.

I'm trying to compare my new app with the previous, but I use the same IabHelper of Bruno Oliveira. And for my previous game Drive API is turned off, but cloud save works.

What did I forget?

Comment: Note that [AppState is deprecated](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/11/keeping-your-saved-games-in-cloud.html) and will no longer allow write access. You should consider using [Saved Games](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/savedgames) for all new games.

Comment: Yes, thank you! Have just found info about it. Do you hapen to know can developers leave old apps as they are, or appstate will stop working at all soon?

Comment: Per the blog post: "In a few months, we will be modifying the old AppState service to be read-only. You'll still be able to read your user's old cloud save games and transfer them to the new Saved Games service, but you'll no longer be able to save games using the old service"

Comment: Thank you for the warning. And what about high scores and achievements? Can I not touch apps that use only them, not appstate?

Comment: Yes, only AppState is affected